# httpRequest.then not getting called

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have some Cloud Clode similar to following and the 'then' in 'someFunction' never gets executed :

```
Parse.Cloud.job('someJobName', function (request, status) {

  var query = new Parse.Query('User');  
  query.find().then(function (results) {
    if (results.length > 0) {
      Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '...',
        otherStuf: ...,    

        success: function (httpResponse) {
          var somePromises = [];
          _.each(results, function (userDataRecord) {
            somePromises.push(someFunction(userDataRecord));
          });

          return Parse.Promise.when(somePromises)
            .then(function () {
              // Do some more stuff
            });
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
          // report error
        }
      });
    }
  });
});


function someFunction(userDataRecord) {
  var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

  promise.then(function () {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: '....',
      ...,
    }).then(function (httpResponse) {
      // Do something here
    });
  });

  return promise;
}
```

Like mentioned above, my problem is that the 'then' part inside 'someFucntion' never gets called. I believe httpRequest retuurns before executing that part because the http call does what it is suppose to and the code that resides in the '// Do some more stuff' gets executed properly.

What I need is for that code to excute but, before that, the code inside 'then' on 'someFunction' has to be called.

I'm most likely doing something wrong here.

**EDIT**

I got it to work by moving the 'then' to the pomisse itself

```
function someFunction(userDataRecord) {
  var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

  promise.then(function () {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: '....',
      ...,
    });
  }).then(function (httpResponse) {
      // Do something here
  });

  return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Parse.Cloud.httpRequest](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.httpRequest) returns promise so you could rewrite the `someFunction` as following:

```
Parse.Cloud.job('someJobName', function (request, status) {

    var query = new Parse.Query('User');
    return query.find().then(function (results) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '...',
                otherStuf: ""
            }).then(function (httpResponse) {
                var somePromises = [];
                _.each(results, function (userDataRecord) {
                    somePromises.push(someFunction(userDataRecord));
                });
                return Parse.Promise.when(somePromises)
            }).then(function () {
                // Do some more stuff

                status.success();
                return
            }, function() {
                // error
                status.error();
                return
            });
        }
        status.success()
    });
});

function someFunction(userDataRecord) {
    ...
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: '....',
            ...
        }).then(function (httpResponse) {
        // Do something here
        return ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried that. The 'httpRequest' gets executed but whatever is inside 'then' never gets called.

Comment: Oh, could you try again with placing `return` before `query.find` and `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` in job's callback?

Comment: I don't think I understood.

Comment: Okay, forget about it. I just update the answer, hope it helps you.